# Using Regular Expression to convert Textile italic markup to HTML

Tags: jquery, regex, wordpress, textile

I inherited a Wordpress site with a few years worth of Textile markup in image captions. Rather than stripping them out I'd like to use some jQuery to turn italics that have been marked up like this:

```
Hello this is some _italic text_ here.
```

to this

```
Hello this is some <em>italic text</em> here.
```

Thanks, here is what I tried, based on the answers below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function() {
jQuery("p.wp-caption-text").each(function(n) {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("_([^{]*)_"), "<i>$1</i>");
    });
});
</script>
```

It works, but in my markup sometimes it doesn't seem to find the second _ character.

Here is a real-world example:

```
  <p class="wp-caption-text">Left: Paul Klee, _Grosses Tier (Large Beast)_, 1928; fractional and promised gift of the Djerassi Art Trust. Right:  Andrew Schoultz, _Three Caged Beasts_, 2011; Courtesy the artist and Marx &amp; Zavattero; © Andrew Schoultz</p>
```

For this one, it produces this:

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">Left: Paul Klee, <i>Grosses Tier (Large Beast)_, 1928; fractional and promised gift of the Djerassi Art Trust. Right:  Andrew Schoultz, _Three Caged Beasts</i>, 2011; Courtesy the artist and Marx &amp; Zavattero; © Andrew Schoultz</p>
```

Any idea how the regexp could be modified to fix this?

Comment: Your regexp `_([^{]*)_` replaces `_[anything but {]_` this don't work try: `_([^_]*)_`  Now it replaces `_[anything but _ ]_`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str  = 'Hello this is some _italic text_ here.'; 
var str = str.replace(/_([^_]+)_/,"<em>$1</em>");
```

if you have a lots of text to make as intalic,you must  use the "g" flag in you regexp to get all matches.

Comment: This *almost* works just as I want it. But it runs into problems when the string has multiple occurances of '_', for example: _this_ and _that_ must be italic'. It will do 'this_ and _that' in italic, not 'this' and 'that'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(function() {
        jQuery("p.wp-caption-text").each(function(n) {
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("{link:([^}]*)}([^{]*){/link}"), "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>");
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("{i}([^{]*){/i}"), "<i>$1</i>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

You are not replacing `[link...]...[/link]` but `{link...}...{/link}` and the with `i` if you want `[..]` instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(function() {
        jQuery("p.wp-caption-text").each(function(n) {
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("\[link:([^\[]*)\]([^\[]*)\[/link\]"), "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>");
            this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("\[i\]([^\[]*)\[/i\]"), "<i>$1</i>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Maybe there is a typo

Sorry. !

For my NOT reading the question attitude :)

See the other. Its working

And what is been with using `g`:

```
var str  = 'Hello this is some _italic text_ here.'; 
var str = str.replace(/_([^_]+)_/g,"<em>$1</em>");
```